# Disable Cell Content detection using vba

Tags: vba, excel, cells

I need to know how to disable cell content detection using VBA, because when I'm importing data from a *.CSV file, I don't want to get Dates in "Date Format" even if I specify that is just text when it imports. I'd like to get Dates as String. If I try to change format after importing I get a number instead of a string with the date.

```
Cells.Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "@"

'importo los datos
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=datosConexion, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .name = archivo
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 65001
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileDecimalSeparator = "."
    .TextFileThousandsSeparator = ","
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Comment: How about appending an apostrophe at the beginning of each string?

`"'" & string`

Comment: Any idea how can I do it with that code? Because I don't read row by row the *.csv file. I just recorded a macro and I used that code , changing what necessary, for my porpose @kaybee99??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change:

```
.TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

For the column(s) that contain the dates you need imported as *Text,* replace the **1** with **xlTextFormat**

Comment: Could I change all "ones" for xlTextFormat? I just need text.

Comment: I can't give you a definite answer without seeing your data.  **Backup your VBA and try it.**